# Safari can’t verify the identity of the website

Tags: macos, safari

Why I am getting this pop-up, regardless of whatever website i open? Because of this its not loading developer.apple.com too!! Any suggestions?

[image: Pop-Up image]

Comment: Can you try a different browser to see if the issue is browser related?

Comment: Bad luck. It occurs on firefox as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certificate errors often stem from incorrect system dates set.

If you've already tried clearing existing certificates from your keychain using Keychain.app, then it's time to open your System Preferences and reset your time and date — ideally automatically.